# What indicates the end of a TCP stream?

Tags: http, networking, tcp

I'm attempting to make a low-level packet reader, sort of like wireshark, for learning purposes and fun.

Going into http parsing, I quickly found that there are these TCP streams, and that data doesn't all come in one packet.

**EDIT:** What I consider to be the stream I've been told is not the right term.  David Schwartz referred to it as a *Query* and EJP as a *Sequence of Segments*.

So I did a little reading on TCP, and I've read everywhere about the **sequence** and **acknowledgment** numbers, how they increase and wrap around etc..
Connection establishment and termination I already had knowledge of.

To be honest I've never been too good at interpretation or using google, but I've been at this for a bit, and I just can't seem to understand how the server/client **ends** a TCP stream.

I'm asking this because, after sending the totality of the http request, the server immediately replies with the page, so, as I've been going back and forward through packets in wireshark and I can't seem to find what delimits this stream (anything indicating length in the first packet or difference between the penultimate and last packets).

Is there no actual delimiter in TCP, and you just get the total length from the http headers's `Content-Length`?

[image: http request]

As seen here, the first 3 packets are connection establishment.
The 3 after those are the sending of the http request (with first being ACK (the selected one), and the latest 2 being PSH & ACK). 
The two after those are ACKs from the server, followed by the entirety of the response.
The last one is my ACK and the connection is never closed for the time I "recorded".

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_termination

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth `Connection establishment and termination I already had knowledge of.`

Comment: The HTTP specification explains how to find the end of a query. You have to connect your TCP receive stream to your HTTP parser's input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The end of a TCP stream is marked by a segment whose FIN bit is sent.

However that isn't the answer to your real question, which is about the end of an HTTP request or response, which is determined by:

1. The Content-length, if present, or
2. The final chunk in a chunked transfer, if used, or
3. The FIN

if there is a body, otherwise the blank line after the headers as pointed out by @Barmar below.

Comment: This is only true of the request if it contains a body, as in `POST` and `PUT` requests. `GET` doesn't have a body, the request ends at the blank line after the header.

Comment: So "stream" and "connection" mean the same thing? From what I've seen in something like an HTTP request/response there can be multiple segments, and that's what I thought to be a stream, since connections can be kept alive. What I was asking was about the "final chunk". How do I know it is the final chunk?

Comment: @TrisT Yes, they are the same thing. The final chunk has length zero if I remember correctly. It's all in RFC 2616. But there are no chunks in a GET request, because there is no request body to chunk.

Comment: @EJP so what would you call the gathering of the sequences used to transfer for example a file? I've edited my question to include an image that shows a connection where the http request is sent in 3 different packets, and that doesn't get terminated in the end. (also the last packet isn't length 0 and it actually contains the post data, where the second contains a part of the cookies)

Comment: I would call it a sequence of segments. But TCP is just a byte stream from the point of view of the user.

Comment: If you want to ask me another question, ask it here. I'm not chasing links. If you're just commenting on your own question, do so under your question.

Comment: A RST ACK can also indicate termination; Web servers and browsers are notorious for taking this short-cut to terminate rather than spending the 4 packets on a graceful termination