HTTP Keep Alive and TCP Protocol: what indicates the end of a client's payload
In HTTP Keep Alive, a persistent TCP connection is re-used for multiple HTTP requests.
When the client has sent all of the data it needs to for a HTTP request, how does the server know the client has sent everything (so the server can start processing the request and send a response)? Same question in reverse for the client, how does it know the server has sent the entire response?
My suspicion is that it's handled in the TCP layer, but haven't been able to find a clear explanation of this.
Related (but doesn't answer this specific question): HTTP Keep Alive and TCP keep alive

Basically, the Content-Length header. I'm not sure whether there's more to it than that...
(Ah, it looks like Transfer-Encoding as well, for chunks...) See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49256096 which is sort of a duplicate.

"It must be handled in the TCP layer" - what led you to that conclusion?

Also, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47642718/what-indicates-the-end-of-a-tcp-stream

Does this answer your question? Detect end of HTTP request body,  How HTTP Server inform its clients that the response has ended. Or better than to rely on some answers - read the actual standard: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3

This is covered by the HTTP protocol specification.
RFC 7230 Section 6.3 says:

In order to remain persistent, all messages on a connection need to have a self-defined message length (i.e., one not defined by closure of the connection), as described in Section 3.3.  A server MUST read the entire request message body or close the connection after sending its response, since otherwise the remaining data on a persistent connection would be misinterpreted as the next request.  Likewise, a client MUST read the entire response message body if it intends to reuse the same connection for a subsequent request.

Section 3.3.3 outlines the rules for determining the length of a message body (for both requests and responses):

The length of a message body is determined by one of the following (in order of precedence):

Any response to a HEAD request and any response with a 1xx (Informational), 204 (No Content), or 304 (Not Modified) status code is always terminated by the first empty line after the header fields, regardless of the header fields present in the message, and thus cannot contain a message body.

Any 2xx (Successful) response to a CONNECT request implies that the connection will become a tunnel immediately after the empty line that concludes the header fields.  A client MUST ignore any Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding header fields received in such a message.

If a Transfer-Encoding header field is present and the chunked transfer coding (Section 4.1) is the final encoding, the message body length is determined by reading and decoding the chunked data until the transfer coding indicates the data is complete.
If a Transfer-Encoding header field is present in a response and the chunked transfer coding is not the final encoding, the message body length is determined by reading the connection until it is closed by the server.  If a Transfer-Encoding header field is present in a request and the chunked transfer coding is not the final encoding, the message body length cannot be determined reliably; the server MUST respond with the 400 (Bad Request) status code and then close the connection.
If a message is received with both a Transfer-Encoding and a Content-Length header field, the Transfer-Encoding overrides the Content-Length.  Such a message might indicate an attempt to perform request smuggling (Section 9.5) or response splitting (Section 9.4) and ought to be handled as an error.  A sender MUST remove the received Content-Length field prior to forwarding such a message downstream.

If a message is received without Transfer-Encoding and with either multiple Content-Length header fields having differing field-values or a single Content-Length header field having an invalid value, then the message framing is invalid and the recipient MUST treat it as an unrecoverable error.  If this is a request message, the server MUST respond with a 400 (Bad Request) status code and then close the connection.  If this is a response message received by a proxy, the proxy MUST close the connection to the server, discard the received response, and send a 502 (Bad Gateway) response to the client.  If this is a response message received by a user agent, the user agent MUST close the connection to the server and discard the received response.

If a valid Content-Length header field is present without Transfer-Encoding, its decimal value defines the expected message body length in octets.  If the sender closes the connection or the recipient times out before the indicated number of octets are received, the recipient MUST consider the message to be incomplete and close the connection.

If this is a request message and none of the above are true, then the message body length is zero (no message body is present).

Otherwise, this is a response message without a declared message body length, so the message body length is determined by the number of octets received prior to the server closing the connection.



So, if the client wants to use HTTP keep-alive, it has to include either a Transfer-Encoding: chunked or Content-Length header in its request message. The server would then receive the request headers and analyze them to determine whether a message body is present, what format it is being transmitted in, and as such how its end is signaled, then the server can read until the logical end of the body is reached.
Likewise, the same thing for server responses in the other direction.  If the server wants to honor the keep-alive, it would send a response message that has either a Transfer-Encoding: chunked or Content-Length header, and then the client would analyze the headers and read the body accordingly until its logical end is reached.
At that point, if both parties agreed to the keep-alive, then the connection should be clear and can be reused for the next request.

It's really the end of the HTTP Payload that the server/client cares about, which is not a part of the TCP layer.
So it's indicated by either:

The Content-Length header
The Transfer-Encoding header Are HTTP keep-alive connections possible without content-length headers?

When the TCP connection is closed (typically due to inactivity timeout) A FIN/RST packet is typically sent at the TCP layer. What indicates the end of a TCP stream?
